# SSL Invalidated by Javascript

Tags: javascript, ssl

I have a webpage that requires SSL, but this one line of Javascript appears to invalidate the SSL encryption. Is there any way to stop this line from executing if the page requires SSL?

```
var api_url ="http://books.google.com/books?...";
```

That line is the problem....Google Books does not allow SSL connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line you've quoted only assigns a value to a variable - it doesn't actually make a request. ASSUMING you've closed the string in your real code:

```
var api_url="http://books.google.com/books";
```

then it won't generate an error. Also, if you're making an AJAX request to Books, you specify the complete URL (including the protocol [http|https]), so the fact that the page that's hosting the JavaScript was retrieved via SSL shouldn't make a difference.

Post some of the surrounding code so we can see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

In your Javascript check `document.location.protocol`, for example:

```
if (document.location.protocol != 'https:')
{
    var api_url ="http://books.google.com/books? 
}
```

Comment: I fixed the problem. if (document.location.protocol != 'https:')
{
document.write(unescape(scriptLine));
} That was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This will return true if client browser is using SSL on current location, false otherwise:

```
document.location.protocol == 'https:'
```